# Changing text in a list

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, html-lists, pinnacle-cart

I have two categories in my brand new [14 day Pinnacle cart free trial](http://a470.carttrial.com) with two categories (Welsh then English):

> "Llyfrau [Books]"
>
> "Anrhegion [Gifts]"

I need a function to remove the language that's not needed. I've got it working for product description, but not for the categories.

in Welsh I am getting

> "ANRHEGION"
>
> "ANRHEGION"

and in English:

> "GIFTS"
>
> "GIFTS"

This is the code that's not quite there! It's what I call the function that's not quite right I think - `.panel-catalog-categories .content ul li a span` ???

Edit - this is all the code I've added from the clean install:

```
{if $current_language.language_id == "1"}

  {literal}

  <script type="text/javascript">

   (function($,h,c){var a=$([]),e=$.resize=$.extend($.resize,{}),i,k="setTimeout",j="resize",d=j+"-special-event",b="delay",f="throttleWindow";e[b]=250;e[f]=true;$.event.special[j]={setup:function(){if(!e[f]&&this[k]){return false}var l=$(this);a=a.add(l);$.data(this,d,{w:l.width(),h:l.height()});if(a.length===1){g()}},teardown:function(){if(!e[f]&&this[k]){return false}var l=$(this);a=a.not(l);l.removeData(d);if(!a.length){clearTimeout(i)}},add:function(l){if(!e[f]&&this[k]){return false}var n;function m(s,o,p){var q=$(this),r=$.data(this,d);r.w=o!==c?o:q.width();r.h=p!==c?p:q.height();n.apply(this,arguments)}if($.isFunction(l)){n=l;return m}else{n=l.handler;l.handler=m}}};function g(){i=h[k](function(){a.each(function(){var n=$(this),m=n.width(),l=n.height(),o=$.data(this,d);if(m!==o.w||l!==o.h){n.trigger(j,[o.w=m,o.h=l])}});g()},e[b])}})(jQuery,this);

   jQuery(document).ready(function()

   {

     //call remove brackets if english
      // Product page- Common
      // Description .page-product .product-description

     displayEnglish(".product-description .product-page-block-content");


      // .catalog-product-title"); ???
      // .panel-catalog-categories .title  ????
      displayEnglish(".panel-catalog-categories .content ul li a span");

      //function to select english

      function displayEnglish(text_selector) {
        if($(text_selector).length> 0) {
          var english_text = $(text_selector).text().match(/\[([^/]]+)\]/g);
          jQuery(text_selector).text(english_text[0].slice(1, -1));
      }
    }

   });

  </script>

  {/literal}

  {else}

  {literal}

  <script type="text/javascript">

   (function($,h,c){var a=$([]),e=$.resize=$.extend($.resize,{}),i,k="setTimeout",j="resize",d=j+"-special-event",b="delay",f="throttleWindow";e[b]=250;e[f]=true;$.event.special[j]={setup:function(){if(!e[f]&&this[k]){return false}var l=$(this);a=a.add(l);$.data(this,d,{w:l.width(),h:l.height()});if(a.length===1){g()}},teardown:function(){if(!e[f]&&this[k]){return false}var l=$(this);a=a.not(l);l.removeData(d);if(!a.length){clearTimeout(i)}},add:function(l){if(!e[f]&&this[k]){return false}var n;function m(s,o,p){var q=$(this),r=$.data(this,d);r.w=o!==c?o:q.width();r.h=p!==c?p:q.height();n.apply(this,arguments)}if($.isFunction(l)){n=l;return m}else{n=l.handler;l.handler=m}}};function g(){i=h[k](function(){a.each(function(){var n=$(this),m=n.width(),l=n.height(),o=$.data(this,d);if(m!==o.w||l!==o.h){n.trigger(j,[o.w=m,o.h=l])}});g()},e[b])}})(jQuery,this);

    jQuery(document).ready(function()

    {

      //call remove brackets if english

      displayWelsh(".product-description .product-page-block-content");

      displayWelsh(".panel-catalog-categories .content ul li a span");
      //function to select welsh

      function displayWelsh(text_selector) {
        if($(text_selector).length> 0) {
          var welsh_text = $(text_selector).text().replace(/\[([^/]]+)\]/g, "");

          jQuery(text_selector).text(welsh_text);
      }
    }

   });

  </script>

  {/literal}

{/if}
```

Comment: We would need to see a lot more of your code here in order to help debug this issue.

Comment: I've now edited my question to include all the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex in the `displayEnglish` function looks wrong - you have:

```
\[([^}]+)\]
```

Which matches an opening `[`, then finds the longest possible run of characters that are not `}`, then a closing `]`.

Presumably the `}` in the negated character set is a typo, and you meant `]`.

---

Very quick Firebug session as an example

```
// existing
> "Anrhegion [Gifts] Llyfrau [Books]".match(/\[([^}]+)\]/g);
["[Gifts] Llyfrau [Books]"]

// fixed
> "Anrhegion [Gifts] Llyfrau [Books]".match(/\[([^\]]+)\]/g);
["[Gifts]", "[Books]"]
```

Comment: Thanks Andrzej for the bug spot - that improves thinks! Now I get: in English - "Gifts" followed by "Gifts" instead of "Books" followed by "Gifts" - nearly there! I've updated http://a470.carttrial.com with your bug fix. Thanks again.

Comment: As the infamous jwz once said: "Some people, when confronted with a problem, think “I know, I'll use regular expressions.”   Now they have two problems."

Comment: @user1732029: Well, look at the output of the regex match - it's an array (with two elements in the successful case).  Now look at your code.  Explain to me how you think it will use the first match in one place, and the second match in the other?

Comment: Hi Andrzej! Thanks again for the feedback. I'm only three days into learning JavaScript, so forgive my mistakes! I was so happy that I managed to get it working with product description, I though that I was very close to getting the Categories list working... Is it possible to pass all the element individually to the function, or is my approach that is totally wrong? Thanks again for your help. tkone - I'm trying to decipher your message, but I think it reads "come back when you are half as clever as I am".. Cheers!

Comment: OK - displayEnglish(".panel-catalog-categories .content ul li:first a span"); // works for the first one - now I need to figure out how does for loops work in JavaSctipt...!

Comment: displayWelsh(".panel-catalog-categories .content ul li[0] a span"); does not work. Can anyone help me? How do you use arrays??

Comment: I've got it working: it's       `code`$(".panel-catalog-categories .content ul li a span").each(function(){
          displayEnglish($(this));
         }); Thanks @AndrzejDoyle for your help